# How to Check column of timestamps for yesterday's date

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a column (the first column in the sheet) of timestamp values.  I am trying to perform a task if the timestamp date is from the day before do some task.

here is the code I came up with from reading other posts on StackOverflow and different sites on the web:

```
if(timestamp[0][0].setDate(timestamp[0][0].getDate()) === yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate())-1) {
do some task
}
```

However, it isn't working and I am not really sure where to go from here.  The first column in my Google Sheet is where the timestamps are.

Comment: Although I don't know about ``timestamp[0][0]``, how about following method? 1 day is 86400000 seconds. Using this, the day before can be written as ``new Date(new Date - 86400000).getDate()``. How about comparison of this? If you want a sample script, feel free to tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike I didn't realize that 86400000 is the total second in a day.  I saw a lot of other people using that in their code, but wasn't sure why, so thanks for explaining that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the date from yesterday, should be able to use it with an If statement.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var now = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date(now.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_DAY);
  Logger.log(yesterday);
  
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(now.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_DAY), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  Logger.log(formattedDate);
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it does pull in yesterday's date in correctly.  However, my timestamp values are formatted like: 5/18/2017 8:24:07.  So, I am not sure what the best way is to use your function to verify if the timestamp has yesterday's date or not.

Comment: How does the "Utilities" work in the Utilities.formatDate(new Date(now.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_DAY)?